# Scope error when using Autofac with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac, signalr

I'm trying to inject an `HttpContextBase` in my SignalR hub:

```cs
public class EventHub : Hub, IDisconnect
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContextBase;

    public EventHub(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
    {
        _httpContextBase = httpContextBase;
    }

    [...]
}
```

The registration code looks like this:

```cs
private static void InitAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    var assembly = typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly;

    builder.RegisterControllers(assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
    builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(InterfaceBasedInjectedClasses())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(InterfaceLessInjectedClasses())
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<SurvivalContainer>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<EventHub>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    var container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));


    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalR.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> [DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a Tag matching
>   'httpRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was
>   requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as
>   per-HTTP request is being reqested by a SingleInstance() component (or
>   a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request
>   dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or
>   ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container
>   itself.]

Stacktrace:

```
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime.FindScope(ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope) +160
Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup..ctor(IComponentRegistration registration, IResolveOperation context, ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +57
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +102
Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +64
Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +164
Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +14
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +70
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, Object& instance) +70
SignalR.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in D:\etc\Dev\SignalR.Autofac\AutofacDependencyResolver.cs:30
SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubActivator.Create(HubDescriptor descriptor) +60
SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.ResolveHub(String hubName) +27
SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateHub(IRequest request, HubDescriptor descriptor, String connectionId, TrackingDictionary state, Boolean throwIfFailedToCreate) +445
SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceivedAsync(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +246
SignalR.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ProcessRequestAsync>b__4(String data) +29
SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessSendRequest() +63
SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessRequestCore(ITransportConnection connection) +70
SignalR.Transports.ForeverTransport.ProcessRequest(ITransportConnection connection) +5
SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +560
SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +120
SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context) +422       SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +68
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I'm just getting started with autofac and SignalR and I find myself a little stuck. None of the related topics on SO helped. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
```

The exception message indicates that, during resolution, something is trying to be resolved from a lifetime scope tagged `httpRequest`. You get registrations like this in Autofac when you register something `InstancePerHttpRequest()`:

```
// These two are roughly equivalent:
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");
```

If you look at the source of the `AutofacWebTypesModule` it registers the web abstractions (like `HttpContextBase`, the thing you're looking for) as `InstancePerHttpRequest`.

Further, if you look at the way the `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver` works, whenever you resolve a type during a request, it creates a new, nested, named lifetime scope tagged with `httpRequest`. This allows you to have that magic `InstancePerHttpRequest`.

Under the assumption the `SignalR.Autofac` library you're using is [the one here](https://github.com/thinktecture/SignalR.Autofac), which is also [the one on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR.AutoFac)), looking in the [`SignalR.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver`](https://github.com/thinktecture/SignalR.Autofac/blob/master/AutofacDependencyResolver.cs), **no such nested/named lifetime scope is being created for service resolution**.

Thus, when Autofac tries to resolve the `HttpContextBase` dependency, it can't find that `httpRequest` tagged scope (because it doesn't exist) and issues the error you're seeing.

**There is no simple answer for this**. The nested `httpRequest` scope is actually important because it basically can't exist *outside* of a real web request. It makes it "safe" - you can't get an `HttpContextBase` if there's no web context (say, at application startup).

If you need to inject an `HttpContextBase` and you're sure that your `EventHub` will only live for one web request and that's it (I'm no SignalR guy, so bear with me), it means you either need to:

- Request a fix for this from the SignalR.Autofac project.
- Implement your own custom SignalR.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver that handles things the way the MVC resolver does.

Without actually doing the work and testing it out myself, I can't really provide specific guidance on how to accomplish that. *This exercise is left to the reader.*

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks, this is useful. I was under the impression other people had the whole thing working. I'll have to dig into autofac and SignalR a little more than what I had really wanted but lets see how I go.

Comment: I'm glad to report I got something working using a mix of  http://alexmg.com/post/2010/11/04/ASPNET-MVC-3-Beta-integration-for-Autofac.aspx and the SignarR.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver (which I'm not using anymore). Thanks!