# Automapper & Autofac typeconverter - does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, automapper, autofac

I'm having issues getting aufotac to inject into my autopmapper typeconverters. I've tried some different ways but I'm currently stuck using the code below. The closest I've come to finding a solution is the code below (borrowed small bits from http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.se/2011/10/autofac-automapper-custom-converter-di.html). His sample seems to work 1:1 but haven't been able to locate what I'm missing. As usual extracted the relevant bits, let me know if it's insufficient.

My autofac bootstrapper:

```
public class AutoFacInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //Mvc
            var MvcContainer = BuildMvcContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(MvcContainer));

            //Web API
            var ApiContainer = BuildApiContainer();
            var ApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(ApiContainer);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = ApiResolver;
        }

        private static IContainer BuildApiContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
            return BuildSharedDependencies(builder, assembly);
        }

        private static IContainer BuildMvcContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var assembly = typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
            return BuildSharedDependencies(builder, assembly);
        }

        private static IContainer BuildSharedDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly)
        {
            //----Build and return container----
            IContainer container = null;

            //Automapper
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)).AsSelf();
            AutoMapperInitializer.Initialize(container);
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).Where(t => typeof(IStartable).IsAssignableFrom(t)).As<IStartable>().SingleInstance();

            //Modules
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new NLogLoggerAutofacModule());

            //Automapper dependencies
            builder.Register(x => Mapper.Engine).As<IMappingEngine>().SingleInstance();

            //Services, repos etc
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SqlRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerDependency();
            
            container = builder.Build();
            return container;
        }
    }
```

My Automap bootstrapper / initializer:

```
namespace Supportweb.Web.App_Start
{
    public class AutoMapperInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(IContainer container)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(map =>
            {
                map.CreateMap<long?, EntityToConvertTo>().ConvertUsing<LongToEntity<NavigationFolder>>();

                map.ConstructServicesUsing(t => container.Resolve(t)); 
            });
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

The typeconverter that im trying to get working:

```
public class LongToEntity<T> : ITypeConverter<long?, T>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<T> _repo;

        public LongToEntity(IRepository<T> repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public T Convert(ResolutionContext context) 
        {
            long id = 0;
            if (context.SourceValue != null)
                id = (long)context.SourceValue;
            return _repo.Get(id);
        }
    }
```

Except for the converter all mappings works fine. The error seems to indicate that I'm lacking an ioc reference but I've tried but the mentioned ITypeConverter<,> and LongToEntity<> and variations which doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have three problems with your current code:

1. You need to call `ConstructServicesUsing` **before** registering any mapping as described in the linked article:

   > The tricky thing is we need to call that method before we register mapper classes.

   So the correct `Mapper.Initialize` is the follwing:

   ```cs
   Mapper.Initialize(map =>
           {
               map.ConstructServicesUsing(t => container.Resolve(t));  

               map.CreateMap<long?, EntityToConvertTo>()
                   .ConvertUsing<LongToEntity<NavigationFolder>>();
           });
   ```
2. Because your `LongToEntity<T>` is an open generic you cannot use `AsClosedTypesOf` but you need to use here also the `RegisterGeneric` for the registration:

   So change your `ITypeConverter<,>` registration from:

   ```cs
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
           .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>)).AsSelf();
   ```

   To use the `RegisterGeneric` method:

   ```cs
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LongToEntity<>)).AsSelf();
   ```
3. Because you have moved the Automapper initialization into a separate method  `AutoMapperInitializer.Initialize` you cannot use the clojure trick from the article, so you need to call it **after** you have created the container:

   ```cs
    container = builder.Build();
    AutoMapperInitializer.Initialize(container);
    return container;
   ```

Comment: Thx for the input. I have moved the initializer and constructservices around earlier but didnt notice any differences. Though completely overlooked the registergeneric part.

Ajdusted according to your advice and now get another error when running, "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested."

Comment: Then  you have a completely unrelated problem now that the Autofac resolution started to working. You should ask this in a different question but first check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802073/scope-error-when-using-autofac-with-signalr which seems similar to your problem.

Comment: Without seeing your complete registration it is hard to tell what causing the problem. Probably in your `LongToEntity` you are referencing (maybe in the `IRepository` implementations) some types which were registered with `InstancePerLifetimeScope`...

Comment: Found it. I was injecting my DbContext as 'InstancePerHttpRequest'. When changing to per dependency it works = it was the generic registration i missed that gave me the main headache so thanks for steering me on the right path ;)

Think i had issues when injecting in the default manner earlier but seems to be working now. Anyway the main issue seems to be solved now!